# Wait for all observables in mergeMap to complete before emitting a custom value

Tags: rxjs, reactivex, mergemap

I want to process a list of observables concurrently using `flatMap` and then to emit a single empty value when all inner observables are processed. Is there an elegant way to achieve this, i.e. using a single operator?

Here's the example:

```js
const { of, from } = Rx.Observable;

from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
  .mergeMap(number => multiply(number), 2) // processing two numbers at a time
  .last() // waiting for all inner observables to complete
  .map(_ => undefined) // casting a value returned by last() to an empty value
  .subscribe()
;

function multiply(number) {
  return of(number * 2) // multiplying the number
    .delay(200) // adding a slight delay
  ;
}
```

I know I can use `toArray()` or `last()` to wait for all inner observables to complete, but then I will need to cast it to an empty value using `map()` operator (as in my example above).

I guess, I'm looking for an operator with the following semantics: `emit X when source observable completes`, e.g.:

```js
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
  .mergeMap(number => multiply(number), 2)
  .emitOnComplete(undefined)
  .subscribe(console.log) // we should get undefined here
;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's actually one sneaky solution using `reduce()` that emits only once when its source observable completes. You can use it to ignore all values and just return the seed value:

```
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(number => multiply(number), 2),
    reduce((acc, value) => acc, undefined),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tx6bbe

Btw, funny fact: The same trick with `reduce()` is used [inside Angular's Router package](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/532e53678d423e29abff7855d5b6eef0ab5dd5eb/packages/router/src/operators/resolve_data.ts#L36) (just without the seed value).

Comment: Hah! That's clever, thanks. However, I can't say that I like this solution's semantics, it's hard to understand what's going on from the first glance. I guess `endWith(undefined)` is much more readable.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't use that either because `ignoreElements()` + `endWith()` makes more sense but you asked for a single operator :).

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way that I've managed to find so far is combining [ignoreElements](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/ignoreelements) operator with [endWith](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/endwith):

```js
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .mergeMap(number => multiply(number), 2)
  .ignoreElements()
  .endWith(undefined)
  .subscribe(console.log) // getting undefined here
;
```

However, it would be really nice to have a single operator for this.