# Wait for all observables from a mergeMap to complete before performing a side effect

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm still new to rxjs, so I'm having trouble on how to do this. I want to perform a side effect when all the observables from my mergeMap completes, but I don't know how to "split" the original stream into a new one.

It looks like from here [Wait for all observables in mergeMap to complete before emitting a custom value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837964/wait-for-all-observables-in-mergemap-to-complete-before-emitting-a-custom-value) that I can use `ignoreElements` and `endsWith(undefined)` but I'd like to keep the original observables from the mergeMap alive

e.g.

```
action$.pipe(
filter(..),
mergeMap(action => nextAction(action)),
performSideEffectWhenMergeMapDone()
```

How do I do this?

I've also tried something like this:

```
  const next = action$.pipe(
    filter(..),
    mergeMap(...))

  next.pipe(
    ignoreElements(),
    endWith(undefined),
    tap(() => {...}
    })
  );
  return next
```

but the tap() never gets hit since the second epic is never registered

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly all this is a part of Redux action? `endWith()` won't help you in this case because `endWith()` will only emit when its source Observable completes but Redux source of actions never completes.

What exactly you should do depends on what `nextAction` is. If it returns an Observable that completes you could do it like this:

```
action$.pipe(
filter(..),
mergeMap(action => nextAction(action).pipe(
  tap({
    complete: () => performSideEffectWhenMergeMapDone()
  }),
)),
```

In other words, you'll wait for the inner Observble in `mergeMap` to complete, not the outer Observable where `mergeMap` is used.

Comment: Ah, okay. This makes sense. This is indeed part of a redux action. Moving the tap inside worked, but also isn't quite what i'm looking for. nextAction in this case is also a `mergeMap` eg `doSomething(action).expand(..).mergeMap(..)`  so tap complete is triggering on action

Comment: **Side Note:** `const fn = () => gn()` is the same as just `const fn = gn`. The two are semantically identical. Though actually the first might be slightly slower because it's two function calls instead of one. They will always produce the same results.

Answer (score -1):

Just like subscribe, tap and can take an `observer`(or a partial `observer`).

An `observer`has this shape:

```ts
{
  next: v => {...},
  error: e => {...},
  complete: () => {...}
}
```

In this case, a partial `observer` that implements complete is enough:

```ts
action$.pipe(
  filter(..),
  mergeMap(action => nextAction(action)),
  tap({
    complete: performSideEffectWhenMergeMapDone
  })
);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working. perhaps because i have another nested mergeMap?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean more specifically?

Comment: left a comment above in martin's answer!